# constexpr value defined in header file cased problem,how to solve it?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, constexpr

a.h

```
constexpr uint64_t seed = strhash_ct(__TIME__);
//seed in a.h must be constexpr,baseuse i want to put it in template,like this:
HashJic::ensure_compile_time<seed>::value
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
uint64_t b = seed;
```

c.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
uint64_t c = seed;
```

In this case b != c
How can I get the same value?

extra information 1：`strhash_ct is a constexpr function`

Comment: Even if you make it `inline` it's still probably going to be an ODR violation because `__TIME__` won't actually be the same in the different translation units. You might have to pick a translation unit that will hold its definition that other ones can refer to instead of trying to make it inline.

Comment: Create a prebuild command (or similar) to generate *seed_time.h* with prebuild time, so it can be shared between the different translation units

Answer (score 0):

1. constexpr is not constinit. Is strhash_ct a constexpr or consteval function?
2. Each translation unit gets own seed variable.
3. In the code snippet above, constexpr is not necessary.

```
a.h
extern const uint64_t seed;

a.cpp
// One definition
const uint64_t seed = strhash_ct(__TIME__);

b.cpp
#include "a.h"
uint64_t b = seed;

c.cpp
#include "a.h"
uint64_t c = seed;
```

In this case `b == c` is true.

Comment: but in this case，seed will not calcuated in compile time,i added this information in the question